# vb.net sql bulkcopy non string values issue

Tags: vb.net

Can I use sqlbulkcopy to insert non string values from a csv file to an sql table?

I have the following code to create a datatable :

```
     Dim dt As New DataTable()
    Dim line As String = Nothing
    Dim i As Integer = 0

    Using sr As StreamReader = File.OpenText("C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Sked Lente\Data\wingrd13.csv")
        line = sr.ReadLine()
        Do While line IsNot Nothing
            Dim data() As String = line.Split(","c)
            If data.Length > 0 Then
                If i = 0 Then
                    For Each item In data
                        dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn())
                    Next item
                    i += 1
                End If
                Dim row As DataRow = dt.NewRow()
                row.ItemArray = data
                dt.Rows.Add(row)
            End If
            line = sr.ReadLine()
        Loop
    End Using
```

I also have the following code to sqlbulkcopy :

```
        Using cn As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("SQLConnStr").ConnectionString)
        cn.Open()
        Using copy As New SqlBulkCopy(cn)
            copy.ColumnMappings.Add(0, 0)
            copy.ColumnMappings.Add(1, 1)
            copy.ColumnMappings.Add(2, 2)
            copy.ColumnMappings.Add(3, 3)
            copy.ColumnMappings.Add(4, 4)
            copy.ColumnMappings.Add(5, 5)
            copy.ColumnMappings.Add(6, 6)
            copy.DestinationTableName = "wingrd13"
            copy.WriteToServer(dt)
        End Using
    End Using
```

I get an error at the line : copy.ColumnMappings.Add(6, 6)

The column in my database is of type real.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

`SqlBulkCopy` will insert the data from your `DataTable` so if you want to insert data that is not text then your `DataTable` has to contain data that is not text.  It's your responsibility to convert the data that you read from the CSV file into the appropriate data types before adding it to the `DataTable`.  The conversion won't happen automatically.

Comment: Thank you so I have used this  : datatabelOesskattings.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Plantjaar", GetType(Integer))). My Sql database column is set to int and not null. Still no luck.

Comment: OK, but did you actually convert the text that you read from the CSV file into `Integer` values before adding it to the `DataTable`?  That's what I explicitly said that you needed to do in my answer.

Comment: Thank you, I used the following :.Add("@PLANTJAAR", SqlDbType.Int, 50, "PLANTJAAR"). Works great now. Thank you once again.